# Can we execute thread in other header file?

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, pthreads

I have 2 files (.c) one for test (test.c) and in test.c I put main function of program and also I have another file that included in test.c and in that I created threads, but when I run test.c threads don't run. But if I define threads in main function it's right. Now I want to know can we use thread in other header files?

this is my main code:

```
include stdlib.h
include stdio.h
include time.h
include math.h
include "msort_pth.h"

//Dynamically allocate an array of size N in heap
void fillArray ( int** values, unsigned int N )
{
  srand(time(0));
unsigned int i;
for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    (*values)[i] = rand() - (RAND_MAX/2);
}

//Check to see if the sorted array is really sorted!
void checkArray ( const int* values, unsigned int N, const int* sorted )
{
   unsigned int i;
for (i=0; i <= N-2; i++)
    if (sorted[i]>sorted[i+1])
    {
    printf("ERROR i=%d %d %d", i, sorted[i], sorted[i+1]);
    return;
    }
printf("OK\n");
  }

int main ( int argc, char* argv[] )
 {
    if ( argc != 3 ){
    printf("Please enter: \n ./a.out  M  K\n");
    exit( 1 );
 }

    //input array
unsigned int K;
unsigned int N;

//Fill in the input array with random data
K = atoi(argv[2]);
N = pow( 2, atoi(argv[1]) );
int* values = (int*) malloc ( sizeof(int) * N );
fillArray ( &values, N );

//Sorted array
int* sorted = (int*) malloc ( sizeof(int) * N );

//Sort the input array and report its runtime
clock_t t1 = clock();
mergeSortParallel ( values, N, K, sorted );
clock_t t2 = clock();
printf("Runtime = %g ms \n", (t2-t1)/1000.0);

//Check for correctness
checkArray ( values, N, sorted );

return 0;
}
```

and this is my thread file:
(Some unnecessary functions are removed)

```
include "msort_pth.h"
include pthread.h
include stdio.h
include stdlib.h


define BLOCKSIZE 1

int* globalValues;
int* globalSorted;
int* globalTemp;
int globalN;
int globalK;
int thread_count;

void merge(int A[], int B[], int N, int* sorted);
void My_BubbleSort(const int* values, int Size, int* sorted);
void My_Sort(const int* values, unsigned int N, int* sorted, int     BLOCK_SIZE);
void mergeSort(const int* values, unsigned int N, int* sorted);
void* threadFunc(void* rank);
 void mergeSortParallel  (const int* values, unsigned int N, unsigned int  K, int* sorted)
{
globalK=K;
globalN=N;
globalValues=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*N);
globalSorted=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*N);
globalTemp=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*N);
int i=0;
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    globalValues[i]=values[i];
}
pthread_t* thread_handles;
long thread=0;
thread_handles=malloc(thread_count*sizeof(pthread_t));
for(thread=0;thread<thread_count;thread++)
{
    pthread_create(&thread_handles[thread],NULL,threadFunc,(void*)thread);
}

for(thread=0;thread<thread_count;thread++)
{
    pthread_join(thread_handles[thread],NULL);
}
free(thread_handles);



printf("GLOBAL VALUES:\n");
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    printf("%d,",values[i]);
}
printf("\n");

printf("\n");
printf("GLOBAL Sorted:\n");
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    printf("%d,",globalSorted[i]);
}



/*
int j=0;
int length=0;
for(j=0;j<globalK;j++)
{
             int p=globalK-j;
    int level=pow(2,p);
    length=globalN/level;
    for(i=0;i<level;i++)
    {
      merge(globalSorted+i*length,globalSorted+(i+1)*length,length,globalTemp);

    }
    for(i=0;i<2*length;i++)
    {

    }

}
 */


}

void* threadFunc(void* rank)
{
long myrank=(long)rank;
 printf("\n MY rank is: %ld \n",myrank);
int start=myrank*(globalN/thread_count);
int length=globalN/thread_count;
mergeSort(globalValues+start,length,globalSorted+start);

return NULL;

}
```

Comment: The question is not very clear to me. However, in general 1.) one won't include a  .c from a .c. 2.) one won't put code to be executed in a header (.h).

Comment: Please show us the faulty code. Where you put code usually doesn't have an effect.

Comment: I expected "ThredFunc" print something on display,but it didn't.

Comment: "*when I run test.c*" you are aware that .c files need to be compiled (and linked) to have the result of this "*run*", aren't you?

Comment: I am. "CodeBlock" compiled it with any error. but in run threadFunc didn't run.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to define a thread in other file (test.c) and run it in main file (main.c). In that case, you want to make "test.h" include the test.h in main.c and test.c.

```
#include "test.h"
```

After that you define the functions in test.c, and declare them in test.h.

test.h should have #ifndef.

And include it in Makefile:

```
debug:clean
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CDEBUGFLAGS) -g -o  main main.c test.c
```

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't my problem.